# Decreasing MySQL ram usage

Tags: mysql, performance, memory

MySQL is using 150MB of my RAM memory when it's doing nothing.

I have a VPS with only 256 MB ram available, so what can I do to decrease its RAM usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are example my.cnf files included with the MySQL packages on most distributions, on RHEL / CentOS they can be found in `/usr/share/mysql`.

my-small.cnf is designed for systems with a small memory footprint, so may be suitable for your application.

Alternatively you could follow a MySQL tuning guide on the web to find the commonly tuned memory parameters and simply decrease rather than increase the values.

Comment: Thanks! Where do I need to put the config file?

Comment: Copy it to /etc/my.cnf - you may want to backup the original first.